# What are the generators of $(\mathbb{R},+)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The real numbers as a group under addition are an infinitely-generated group. I'm not sure what those generators are though (or if it even makes sense to ask the question).

For example, could we say that the generators are $1, 0.1,0.01,\dots$ as a real number can be defined as a limit $\sum_i^n w_i 10^{-i}$ for some $w$?

Comment: well you'll certainly never find a minimal set of generators, for instance .1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1+.1 = 1.

Comment: Maybe you could take a hamel base of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then add also the elements of that base divided by $n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: There are not **the** generators. There are many, many generating systems. Of course $\mathbb{R}$ itsself (as always).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you talk about $\mathbb{R}$ as an abstract group, you've forgotten its [topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space), so you're no longer allowed to say the word "limit." The subgroup generated by the numbers $\frac{1}{10^n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the subgroup of rational numbers with terminating decimal expansions, which is much smaller than the real numbers.

However, if you remember the topology, then $\mathbb{R}$ becomes a [topological group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group), and then it's true that $\mathbb{R}$ is *topologically* generated by the numbers $\frac{1}{10^n}$ in the sense that the closure of the subgroup they generate is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

In practice, though, once we start talking about topological groups it no longer becomes particularly useful to work with generators. Instead, in the special case of [Lie groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) a reasonable substitute is to work with their [Lie algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra), which you can think of as their "infinitesimal generators."

Answer (score 8):

There is no finite set, nor minimal set of generators for $(\mathbb R, +)$, hence, it is an *infinitely generated* (uncountable) group.

Comment: I think this non-existence of a minimal set is the most interesting point of this whole question. It means that if $S$ is a generating set and $x\in S$ then $S\setminus \{x\}$ is also a generating set. Which is cool. It also holds for $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$, and certain other infinitely generated abelian groups (called *divisible* groups, see Babak S.'s answer).

Answer (score 5):

$\Bbb R$ is uncountable, so it definitely isn't finitely generated, or even countably generated. Suppose we had countably many generators, $\{a_{i}\}$. Then every element in $\Bbb R$ can be written as $\sum_i n_{i} a_{i}$ (let's not worry about convergence), where $i$ ranges over $\Bbb N$, and $n_{i} \in \Bbb Z$. However the set of all such expressions is clearly a countable union of countable sets, and is thus countable.

Comment: Why is this a countable union of countable sets?  That's certainly true if you restrict your sums to be finite, but the set of _infinite_ expressions of that form certainly isn't countable; it's indexed by the sequences $\{n_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with cardinality (trivially) $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: I think you need to emphasize that the sums have _finite_ support - $i$ does _not_ (really) range over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: An alternative proof would be to realise the free group on countably-infinitely many generators $F_{\infty}$ as a subgroup of $F_2$. So $F_{\infty}$ is countable, and so are all its quotients. Done.

Answer (score 3):

This hint is a good point but need you to know [Divisible groups](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.brandeis.edu%2F~igusa%2FMath101b%2Fdivisible.pdf&ei=9F1iUcLAIsHQtQb-yYHYAg&usg=AFQjCNHfHSBwVwPmjJLp1MS8hC7CHTKlOw&bvm=bv.44770516,d.Yms&cad=rja). It is not finitely generated because any nontrivial divisible group cannot be finitely generated.