# Can an uncountable group be generated from a single element?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, elementary-set-theory

First question : can an uncountable group be cyclic?

Ok so my though is if $G$ is generated by i then for $x\in G$ we have $x=i^n$ for integer n, so then it must be countable. Is there a way to generate an uncountable group in some way from a single element?

Second question: can an uncountable group be generated by a countable set?

Something related to my question is that for any positive $k: \mathbb Q^k$ is smaller than $\mathbb R$, however since we can approach any number infinitely using a binary system it makes sense to me that if we build $(N,b_1,b_2,b_3....)$ where $ N$ is the whole part of the number and b is 0 or 1 then this should have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

My question is the following: can an uncountable group be generated from a countable group?

> I believe that the set $2^{-n}$ for n a non negative integer does the trick in the group $\mathbb R $under addition. Am I right?

Regards

Comment: Your thought in the first paragraph is absolutely correct, and shows that the answer to the question is no. I am not sure what the question in the second paragraph is.

Comment: Dear Omnitic, I am still finding it difficult to understand what you are asking. Firstly, an element of what? Secondly, how does this relate to what you have written in the second paragraph? What is the element you mean in this case?

Comment: @Omnitic: in some context, say Lie groups, some people would use the terminology "subgroup generated by a set S" to mean the topological closure of the subgroup generated by the set $S$. In this sense, $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by 1, 0.1, 0.01,..., which is probably what you meant in paragraph 2; or $S^1$ would be generated by an irrational angle. But this is a purely terminology issue. If you stick strictly algebraically to groups, then no - your first paragraph already says that subgroup generated by one element is countable.

Comment: @Omnitic the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354413/what-are-the-generators-of-mathbbr) might  interest you

Comment: @stahl that totally answers my question, could you place a link on your answer?

Comment: @Omnitic done, I've also added a bit more detail to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a group is generated by one element, then it is cyclic. However, all cyclic groups are isomorphic to either $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for some $n$ or $\Bbb Z$. $\Bbb Z$ is countable, so any (infinite) group generated by one element must also be countable. We can also see this directly by simply noting that by definition, $G = \langle r\rangle = \{r^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$, so there is an immediate bijection between $G$ and $\Bbb Z$.

As for the second paragraph, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. If you mean for each $b$ to be the same, then there's a bijection between $\{(N,b,b,b,\ldots)\mid N\in\Bbb Z, b\in\{0,1\}\}$ and $\Bbb Z\times\{0,1\}$ (which is countable). If you mean for each $b$ to be possibly different, just notice that if you disregard the $N$, you can put $\{(b_1,b_2,\ldots)\mid b_i\in\{0,1\}\}$ in bijection with $[0,1]$ (which is uncountable) by sending $(b_1,b_2,\ldots)\mapsto .a_1a_2\ldots$, where $.b_1b_2\ldots$ is the base $2$ decimal expansion of $.a_1a_2\ldots$, so you obtain a bijection between $\{(N,b_1,b_2,\ldots)\mid b_i\in\{0,1\}, N\in\Bbb Z\}$ and $\Bbb Z\times [0,1]$ (still uncountable).

The set $\{2^{-n}\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$ will not generate all of $\Bbb R$ as a normal group - it won't even generate all of $\Bbb Q$ (you'll always have powers of $2$ in the denominator)! In fact, it is known in general that if a group is countably generated, it is countable. However, if you want to talk about topological groups, then you can get uncountable groups from countable generating sets, because you take the topological closure in the end. $\Bbb R$ does have a topology, so if you consider the generating set $\{10^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$ as generating a topological group with the usual topology (induced by the Euclidean metric), you can indeed generate all of $\Bbb R$ (think about limits and infinite decimal expansions). However, the key here is that in $\Bbb R$ you *can* make sense of things like infinite sums and limits. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354413/what-are-the-generators-of-mathbbr) for some more commentary.

Comment: But isn't that equal to R? I mean all reals have a base 2 decimal expansion right?

Comment: I left off the $N$ in front for simplicity, but if you throw it back in, you could obtain a bijection between the set I described consisting of $(N,b_1,b_2,...)$'s and $\Bbb R$, because if two sets have the same cardinality, then there exists a bijection betwixt them by definition (and $\left|\Bbb Z\times [0,1]\right| = \left|\Bbb R\right|$). None of the sets I mentioned in my answer is exactly equal to $\Bbb R$, though.

Comment: The expansions you can create are finite (terminating) binary strings.  There are only countably many of them.  It is the same argument as your group-you have have $r^n$ for any finite $n$.  There are countably infinite many of these.

Comment: but I don't want to make n finite... how can I write that set?

Comment: In the topological setup we even have that $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is generated by the single element $\sqrt 2+\mathbb Z$, say.

Answer (score 4):

**Theorem:** An countably generated group is countable.

(Thus, an uncountable group cannot be countably generated.)

*Proof:* The proof is quite easy, in a way. Every countably generated group is the homomorphic image of the (unique) free group on countable many generators $F_{\mathbb{N}}$. So, if you can prove that $F_{\mathbb{N}}$ is countable then you are done. However, this holds as, for example, the commutator subgroup* of $F_2$, the free group on two-generators, is infinitely (and co countably) generated, and subgroups of free groups are free. Done!

*In fact, any proper normal subgroup of infinite index is infinitely generated.

Note: The proof of finitely-generated is low-level and a good exercise.

Answer (score 3):

For a countable set to generate an uncountable "algebraic" system you either need an uncountable number of operations or operations with an infinite number of operands or infinite sets as operands. (I put "algebraic" in quotes because many people would say these possibilities take you outside algebra.)

The additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by numbers of the form $2^{-n}$ is countable (it is a subset of the rational numbers). Yes, there are senses in which $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by these numbers, but this needs an infinitary operation such as the operation that assigns the limit to a Cauchy sequence or the operation that assigns the supremum to a non-empty bounded set.

Comment: Ok, mabye unrelated but i have seen in some places that $\aleph _0^2 =\aleph _1$ isn't this what i'm doing?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Don't you (and possibly also the OP) mean $2^{\aleph_0}$ instead of $(\aleph_0)^2$?

Comment: @TrevorWilson: Yes I do. What nonsense.

Comment: $\aleph_0^2$ is the cardinality of the set of pairs of natural numbers and is equal to $\aleph_0$ which is strictly smaller than the first uncountable cardinal $\aleph_1$. You may be getting mixed up with continuum hypothesis which asserts $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$. I don't think it is relevant to your question.