# Is there a generator for $(\Bbb R, +)$?

Tags: group-theory

I know that the generator for $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is $<1>$, because you can get any number in $\Bbb Z$ as a sum of $1's$ and $-1's$. But what about $(\Bbb R, +)$ how can one find a generator for this group , or is it impossible ?

Comment: No, there is not such a generator of $(\mathbb R, +)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354413/what-are-the-generators-of-mathbbr

Comment: Nice find, @user29418

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the group $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is generated by some $g\in\mathbb{R}$.

Clearly, we can't have $g=0$.

But the group generated by $g$ is the set of integer multiples of $g$, none of which are equal to ${\large{\frac{g}{2}}}$.

Thus, ${\large{\frac{g}{2}}}$ is not in the group generated by $g$, contrary to the assumption that $g$ generates all of $\mathbb{R}$.

It follows that there is no element $g\in\mathbb{R}$ which generates $(\mathbb{R},+)$.